# Op-amp output as gate voltage to MOSFET

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet, circuit-analysis, negative-feedback

[image: Opamp+Mosfet circuit]

As I understand it, the MOSFET here provides negative feedback to the closed-loop op-amp configuration. Hence, Vout2 = 1 V.

Thus, the current through NMOS = Id = 1 mA. So Vout1 = 5 - (RD·Id). Then Vout2 will remain constant and Vout1 will drop linearly until it reaches 1 V.

Thereafter, as Vds falls, the NMOS enters the triode region and the current will start to fall, hence Vout2 will decrease. This will result in an increase of the output of the op-amp.

However, I ran a simulation using an online tool which showed that the output of the op-amp starts increasing earlier than the 1 V point, the point when Vout1 is equal to the output of the op-amp (Vgate in the figure). Can anyone explain this?

[image: graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the MOSFET, \$V_{DS} = V_{out1} - V_{out2}\$ and \$V_{GS} = V_{gate} - V_{out2}\$. At the starting, due to closed-loop control for gate, \$V_{out2}\$ is fixed at 1V or the current through the system is fixed at 1mA.

When \$R_D\$ is close to 0, \$V_{out1}\$ is 5V and \$V_{gate}\$ is slightly larger than 2V to turn the MOSFET on (as \$V_{TH} = 1V\$). Current is 1mA and \$V_{out1}\$ decreases linearly as \$R_{D}\$ increases. Note that in this region, the effective resistance of the MOSFET will change such that
$$
R_D + R_{eff,MOSFET} = 4k\Omega
$$
When \$R_{D} = 4k\Omega\$, \$R_{eff,MOSFET} = R_{ON} = 0\$ or resistance of MOSFET is very less. It cannot decrease any further therfore gate voltage will jump to the rail. The straight line curves that you get for \$R = 3k\Omega\$ to \$4k\Omega\$ is most probably due to step size which, I think, you chose to be \$1k\Omega\$. You can try decreasing the step size to observe what is expected (say 10 or 100 ohms).

Answer (score 2):

The MOSFET is always in the triode region. The constant current is not a result of the MOSFET being in the saturation region, but a result of the closed-loop system controlling the MOSFET gate.

When Vout1 gets very close to 1V the MOSFET resistance drops to Rds(on) which is (more or less) constant with Vgs (and very small for a typical MOSFET) and cannot go any lower-  the op-amp output will snap to the positive rail (or as close as it can get) over a very narrow change in Rd (maybe 1Ω).

That will occur just as Rd gets to 4K in this case (making some assumptions about the MOSFET and op-amp). Above that increasing the resistance is going to behave like a voltage divider with Vout1 = 1K + Rds(on)/(1K + Rds(on) + Rd) \$\approx\$ 1K/(1K+Rd)

Note that this area is a simulation artifact caused by large steps in Rd.

[image]

Reduce the step size in your simulation to see this.

Answer (score 1):

To meet the "demand" under more strenuous operating conditions, the MOSFET gate has to be driven with a progressively higher voltage. In other words, the change from MOSFET saturation region to MOSFET triode region is not a unique clear-cut single-line transition; there is a gradual change from one region to the other as seen in the electrical characteristics of all MOSFETs.

Hence, as drain voltage falls, the effective transconductance also falls and, correspondingly, gate voltage needs to rise to maintain the constant current through the MOSFET: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://www.mks.com/n/mosfet-physics).